# Bound on the fundamental region of a sublattice of a Niemeier Lattice

Tags: lattices, euclidean-lattices

I am working with an 18 dimensional lattice, $W$ say, primitively embedded into a given Niemeier lattice $\mathcal{N}_i$. I am trying to figure out the following: what is the smallest possible fundamental region of $W$ if it contains no roots?

Any help or references are much appreciated!